# How to access the same Spark RDD from more than one session?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, data-sharing

I have common dataset which needs to be used in multiple programs/processes. How can I create one Spark RDD and share the same RDD in multiple scala programs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at IgniteRDD, which might help you to share the RDD in multiple Spark programs https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Spark-Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver). Jobserver's main role is to be a REST interface but a side-effect is that you can keep RDDs alive and share them between jobs.